# How to make git output usage for any command?

Tags: git

For certain subcommands in git, if I do not specify any parameters I get a convenient "usage" output for that command. Example:

```
$ git blame
usage: git blame [options] [rev-opts] [rev] [--] file

    [rev-opts] are documented in git-rev-list(1)

    --incremental         Show blame entries as we find them, incrementally
    -b                    Show blank SHA-1 for boundary commits (Default: off)
    --root                Do not treat root commits as boundaries (Default: off)
    --show-stats          Show work cost statistics
    --score-debug         Show output score for blame entries
    -f, --show-name       Show original filename (Default: auto)
    -n, --show-number     Show original linenumber (Default: off)
    -p, --porcelain       Show in a format designed for machine consumption
    --line-porcelain      Show porcelain format with per-line commit information
    -c                    Use the same output mode as git-annotate (Default: off)
    -t                    Show raw timestamp (Default: off)
    -l                    Show long commit SHA1 (Default: off)
    -s                    Suppress author name and timestamp (Default: off)
    -e, --show-email      Show author email instead of name (Default: off)
    -w                    Ignore whitespace differences
    --minimal             Spend extra cycles to find better match
    -S <file>             Use revisions from <file> instead of calling git-rev-list
    --contents <file>     Use <file>'s contents as the final image
    -C[<score>]           Find line copies within and across files
    -M[<score>]           Find line movements within and across files
    -L <n,m>              Process only line range n,m, counting from 1
    --abbrev[=<n>]        use <n> digits to display SHA-1s
```

However, some subcommands actually do things when no parameters are passed, such as `git log` for example. I've reviewed the documentation for `git help` but I don't see a way to simply display 'usage' for a command instead of pulling up my web browser. Does anyone know how I can force a subcommand to display its usage information to the command line like `git blame` did?

I'm using msysgit 1.9.2 on Windows. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `git add -h` instead of `git add --help`.

```
[:~] $ git add -h
usage: git add [options] [--] <pathspec>...

    -n, --dry-run         dry run
    -v, --verbose         be verbose

    -i, --interactive     interactive picking
    -p, --patch           select hunks interactively
    -e, --edit            edit current diff and apply
    -f, --force           allow adding otherwise ignored files
    -u, --update          update tracked files
    -N, --intent-to-add   record only the fact that the path will be added later
    -A, --all             add changes from all tracked and untracked files
    --ignore-removal      ignore paths removed in the working tree (same as --no-all)
    --refresh             don't add, only refresh the index
    --ignore-errors       just skip files which cannot be added because of errors
    --ignore-missing      check if - even missing - files are ignored in dry run
```

Comment: Normally I do `git help add`, but are `--help` and `-h` fundamentally different? That's a bit strange :)